# Is there a way to call pyside2-uic on Save?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, uic

Is there a way to call pyside2-uic automatically after I save the .ui file?

Comment: What IDE or tool are you using to modify the .ui?

Comment: @eyllanesc Qt Creator, there are any other or better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happend 3 years ago but now I set `qtForPython.uic.liveExecution.enabled` and `qtForPython.rcc.liveExecution.enabled` in vscode v1.79.2 to automacticall recompile *.ui file when it has changed.

Comment: Hi, I'll give it a try and let you know :)